# Is the following inequality valid or not?

Tags: inequality

$ 1 > 1 - \dfrac{1}{x}$ for every $x \in \mathbb{N} $.

Obviously the limit of $1-\dfrac{1}{x}$ as x approaches infinity is $1$, but is this inequality 100% valid? Does it need a proof, and if so, how can you prove this?

Answer (score 3):

Let $x\neq0$

$1>1-\frac{1}x\Leftrightarrow 0>-\frac{1}x$

If $x\in\mathbb{N},x\neq0$ then $x>0$ hence $\frac{1}x>0$, therefore the inequality *always* hold

Answer (score 1):

You could do a quick proof by contradiction to check. Suppose for some $x \in \mathbb{N}$ that $1\leq 1- \frac{1}{x}$. Subract $1$ from both sides and we have $0 \leq -\frac{1}{x}$. This is a contradiction as $-\frac{1}{x}$ is strictly less than zero. We conclude that $1>1-\frac{1}{x}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$.